# apacite bibliography{} command not creating bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

Please excuse me, I'm quite new to LaTeX (and I'm inexperienced with formal formatting to boot). I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve, and haven't been able to find anything online. Therefore I'm forced to ask the good people of stackexchange.

I have a file mybib.bib which contains (among others) the following reference:

```
@Book{hwbible,
ALTauthor = {Winn Rosch},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {The Winn Rosch Hardware Bible},
publisher = {Brady},
year = {1989},
}
```

The inline citations work as expected, but the bibliography does not. It does not actually spit out a bibliography; rather it only spits out the references instead. This is the only output from the command `\bibliography{mybib}`

[image: How the refernces look]

Extra info:
I have the following lines near the beginning of the .tex file:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

Does anyone know what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Do you want `Bibliogrphy` instead of `References` as the title of the bibliography section? By the way you have to remove `ALT` from `ALTauthor`. I would suggest that you read a guide to `bibtex`.

Comment: Wow, it really was that easy. I knew it was gonna be something really stupid. I found a tutorial to bibtex, so I guess I'll read that now.

Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it solved your problem.

Comment: @Guido Can you add an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the bibtex record provided is that the field `ALTauthor` and `ALTeditor` are not recognised fields. Some bibtex templates provide the form with `ALTauthor` `ALTeditor` with the understanding that only one the two fields should be present and the `ALT` part should be removed.  Thus for the example, the entry should look like:

```
@Book{hwbible,
author = {Winn Rosch},
title = {The Winn Rosch Hardware Bible},
publisher = {Brady},
year = {1989},
}
```